# Where can we get Built-in Script of Volume of Trading View

Tags: pine-script, stock, pine-script-v4

I was working on Volume Analysis in Stock Market, There are various Indicators based on Price and Volume, But Volume is a basic Indicator on which many Analysis is Done, But i am not able to extract the Codes like we can do on other Public Indicators.

I have tried to search it on Google or other Trading View Publishers who had already made indicators based on Volume, But no relevant script was obtained

Can Anyone tell from where we can get it's Script Code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the code of the built-in volume indicator.

If you want to the volume values in your script, there is a built-in variable named `volume`.